# Constructing a topos from a Heyting algebra

Tags: lo.logic, topos-theory, categorical-logic

It is true that, given any topos $\mathcal{C}$ with a terminal object $1_\mathcal{C}$, $Sub(1_\mathcal{C})$ is a Heyting algebra.

Now suppose that we start with a Heyting algebra $H$. Is it always possible to guarantee the existence of a topos $\mathcal{C}_H$ such that $Sub(1_{\mathcal{C}_H})$ is isomorphic to $H$?

Comment: If you start with a complete Heyting algebra then there is a Grothendieck topos whose lattice of subterminal objects is isomorphic to it; simply take the topos of sheaves on the Heyting algebra with its natural topology, where a sieve $S$ covers $c$ if $c=\bigvee S$.

Comment: I remember reading that this was an open problem, but I can't find where...

Comment: @Simon There is an unpublished construction of an elementary topos with given Heyting algebra as $Sub(1)$ by the late D. Pataraia. Unfortunately, although in a sense it is my responsibility, it is still not brought to a publishable form. About half of it is secured in two different ways - Peter Johnstone has an alternative reliable account of that half.

Comment: For a Boolean algebra it is in an exercise in Johnstone's first (1977) topos theory book, where it is attributed to Peter Freyd. Roughly, given a Boolean algebra $B$ one takes the limit of the diagram with $(2^n\hookrightarrow B)\mapsto(\text{finite sets})^n$ ranging over the poset of all finite Boolean subalgebras of $B$.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე : good to know ! Is this construction an analogue of the construction which to a frame $\mathcal{O}$ attach the category of $\mathcal{O}$-sets, but using only finite $H$-sets so that one does not have to deal with infinite supremum when stating the axiom for $H$-sets and maps between them ? (that was my first idea when I thought about it but I never really try to pursue it and I was wondering if it works...)

Comment: @Simon The finite ones do not suffice in general, as far as I know from Pataraia. E. g. the finite version works for a Boolean algebra essentially because Boolean algebras are unions of their finite Boolean subalgebras. Whereas a Heyting algebra may fail to have enough finite Heyting subalgebras. Pataraia added to $H$ all the higher order quantifiers freely and then factored them back out using a higher order analog of the Pitts construction.

Comment: @godelian I'm sorry, but what is the natural topology in a Heyting algebra? Any place I can look that up?

Comment: @user102845 It's the one I mentioned, generated by the families $\{a_i \to c\}$ where $\bigvee a_i=c$. Check for localic topoi in e.g., "Sheaves in geometry and logic" by MacLane and Moerdijk.

Comment: @user102845 Just to make sure - sorry if my comment is redundant: the term "topology" in this case means not topology on the set $H$ but rather a Grothendieck topology, equivalent in this case to a family of pairs $(A,c)$ where $c\in H$ and $A\subseteq{\downarrow}_H(c)$ satisfying certain axioms expressing an abstraction of "elements of $A$ (jointly) cover $c$"

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე, is it published now?

Comment: @QuiqueRuiz No :(